# PHP how to check for input is Only English alphabets and numbers

Tags: php

I got customer who like to key in chinese letter for their username, but i don't have the capability to detect it, how do I reject chinese letter as the username and only accept english letter,underscore, dash and  number.

Another question is since there are people entering chinese letter at my sql database, how do i find the row that contain UTF8 chinese letter.

My encoding charset is utf8_general_ci

Thanks

Comment: if your username only accept [a-z], _, -, numbers, why don't you simply reject any string that have anything else inside it?

Comment: /^[A-Za-z_-]+$/

Comment: try with this [a-zA-Z0-9_-]

Comment: select * from table_name where username REGEXP NOT '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]'; @WhatHeyManga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and only accept english letter,underscore, dash and number.

In that case you can tell your code to only accept

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]
```

And use any regex functions to check whether the input confirms to that

**Supplementary question's answer:**

You can find non confirming usernames with  the same Regex

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$'
```

**strong text**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but how do I find out which database row have this chinese charset so i can hard force them.

Comment: select * from table_name where username REGEXP  NOT '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]'; @WhatHeyManga